# Keyboard Shortcut - date/time LibreOffice

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys, libreoffice

In LibreOffice calc it is possible to enter the date into a cell by using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>;</kbd> or the time using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>

Is there a way of creating a shortcut (to this shortcut) such as <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> respectively and how may (can) this be achieved using Settings → Devices → Keyboard → Keyboard Shortcuts which would be especially helpful to users with dexterity issues?

Comment: So in summary, you want <kbd>F9</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> as shortcuts to enter the date/time in a cell? I do not get the "settings - devices - keyboard part of your question. You can change keyboard assignments, including for "Insert Current Date" in LO under Tools - Customize, Keyboard tab.

Comment: @vanadium Got it - thanks... looking in the wrong place (Ubuntu settings) rather than in the application itself.